# Angular 2 and JWT authentication (Auth0)

Tags: angularjs, angular, jwt, auth0

I have an angular 2 app with JWT authentication (Auth0) that after user login stores the profile and token id in the localStorage, the profile contains a "role" attribute to check if the user can access an especific page.
Everything works like a charm but if the user change the role property in the localStorage to "admin" for example and reload the app he can access pages that he is not authorized. How can I handle that?

auth.service.ts:

```
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export Class AuthService {

lock = new Auth0Lock(ID, domain);
user: Object;

constructor() {
  this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
}

public login() {
  // Auth0 method
  this.lock.show({}, (err: string, profile: Object, token: string) => {
    if (err) { console.log(err); return; }

    localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
  });
}

public logout() {
  localStorage.removeItem('profile');
  localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
}

public loggedIn() {
  return tokenNotExpired();
}

public isAdmin() {
   if (this.user['role'] == 'admin') {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
// imports, etc
export Class AppComponent {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['Customers']" *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()">Customers</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['Admin']" *ngIf="auth.loggedIn() && auth.isAdmin()">Admin</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image]

Any ideas to handle that would be appreciated

Comment: You can also add filters in your api to respond 401/403 status for every unauthorized requests. Then on the client side, listen for `401` and `403` http errors for more security. Check out my article on how to do that - http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it's impossible to create fully secured pages/forms, when you have JavaScript front-end framework. I mean, there is always possibility to open any form, when all application is downloaded to and constructed at client side.

For me, it's important to secure back-end api, and leave "hacking" opportunities to junior developers.

If you have such requirements, try to use server side generated framework: php, asp.net mvc, jsp & etc.

> **UPDATE**

As it came up, Angular2 has directive [@CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router-deprecated/index/CanActivate-decorator.html), which gives more accurate way to cancel navigaition. BUT server side authorization is CRITICAL in javascript front-end based applications.

This will help how to deal with JWT in express back-end: [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually I have an express backend for handle users, but I need to check every time the user is an admin to access that page, I thought that had another method to do that, because I need to make an async http request to node to callback the user, I don't know if this is the right way

Comment: You welcome, you can secure data, not form's html itself - this is my recommendation. If I understand correctly, on that page, only admin should be redirected, because that page makes some async call to server? If yes, than why it is problem? You can check access rights on server side, in passed JWT token.

Comment: To access admin page, the user has to be admin. I have a menu with admin link that only admins can see. So when I run my app I need to make a http call to server passing JWT token, return if that user is admin, then show the link or not ?

Comment: Something like, additionaly: 1. if menu is generated on server, than you can include admin link only for 'admin' roles. I suppose you have static menu (not generated on server). 2. if you are using standard declarative way for routes in app, than user will be able to redirect without link. 3. all api methods on that admin page should return 403 from server, otherwise anyone can call your api from Web Browser's console.

Comment: Yes, the menu is static with routerLink, I'm thinking to use @CanActivate() decorator to prevent user access without link.

Comment: Good idea, It will simplify your code, you won't use *ngIf="auth.loggedIn() && auth.isAdmin()" any more. but problem remains same.

Comment: Could you send an async request to your server in the CanActivate method to check the user's role by the JWT?  I believe CanActivate will accept a returned Promise or Observable and only allow the route to activate on successful resolve.

Comment: Maybe, but how can I use my Service inside CanActivate?

Comment: I don't know how can I check if the user is admin by passing the JWT token to server, because it changes everytime

Comment: On server you can check if JWT signature is correct. After you are sure you received correct token, decode it and call your user store for role. You can also add one claim, e.g. isAdmin, to your token and check it on the server. https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt

Comment: Good :) - I will update answer with summary of this chat to help others, if needed